# How do I make my string compare not sensitive to (ignore) minor differences in white space?

Tags: .net, string, unit-testing

I have some tests that check strings that are displayed to the user.

I don’t wish the test to fail to due to changes in the indentations or line breaks etc.  So I am looking for something like a string compare that.

- Ignore while space as the start of the string (easy use string.trim)
- When any number of any type of white space that is next to each other matches in the same way as if it was a single space.

I could start to create a regex, but someone else may have a better solution hence this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writing a custom compare would be tricky if you need it ***just*** to do this for whitespace. 
I would suggest using regex to normalize, i.e.

```
private static readonly Regex normalizeSpace =
        new Regex(@"\s+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
...
string s = normalizeSpace.Replace(input, " ");
```

Obviously normalize both operands and then test for equality as normal.

Comment: This is how I was thinking doing it.

Comment: @Ian see also the comment I added to PVitt's reply - it depends on the exact rules of "similar enough"

Answer (score 22):

You can use [CompareOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
String.Compare(a, b, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols);
```

Extract from MSDN:

> Indicates that the string comparison must ignore symbols, such as
>   white-space characters, punctuation, currency symbols, the percent
>   sign, mathematical symbols, the ampersand, and so on.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether "abc def" is different to "abcdef" (which is a *more* than just an adjacent whitespace change), and whether "x + y" is different to "x * y"

Comment: While this is certainly interesting, it is clearly not a good fit for the OP's request.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following custom function

```
        public static string ExceptChars(this string str, IEnumerable<char> toExclude)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = str[i];
                if (!toExclude.Contains(c))
                    sb.Append(c);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static bool SpaceInsenstiveComparision(this string stringa, string stringb)
        {
            return stringa.ExceptChars(new[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r' }).Equals(stringb.ExceptChars(new[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r' }));
        }
```

And then use it following way

```
"Te  st".SpaceInsenstiveComparision("Te st");
```

Answer (score -2):

I wrote a small function that trims the input-string both at the start and at the end. Then it goes in a loop to check for double spaces and while there are double spaces, it will replace them by one. So at the end you'll only keep one space.

```
private static string RemoveSpaces(string input)
{
    input = input.Trim();
    while (input.Contains("  "))
        input = input.Replace("  ", " ");
    return input;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: "white space" is more then just " "